# Code to insert image works in HTML but not in JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp

I used following code to insert image in jsp page (netbeans):

```
<div class="split0 top">
               <img align="center" src="C:/Users/pc/Desktop/Pictures/neosphere.png" alt="Missing Picture"/>
    </div>
```

The class was as shown in the code below:

```
.split0 {
height: 20%;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
overflow-x: hidden;
padding-top: 20px;

}
.top{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right:0;
    background-color: #488813;
}
```

This code did not work there and "Missing Picture" was displayed all the time. But when I created simple html page (notepad) with following code, the image was displayed by browser.

```
<html>
<body>
<img align="center" src="C:/Users/pc/Desktop/Pictures/neosphere.png" alt="Missing Picture"/>
</body>
</html>
```

What may be the reason behind failure in displaying image in JSP page?

Comment: Check path name carefully !!

Comment: I used same path in html as well. But it worked there.

Comment: when calling a web page via browser (e.g. localhost:8080) a link to local files shall never work because of security...

Comment: So what might be solution for this?

Comment: Thanks Avijit :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the answer of this question. Have a look at following code:

```
try{
  String imgName="C:\\Users\\pc\\Desktop\\Pictures\\neosphere.png";
  BufferedImage bImage = ImageIO.read(new File(imgName));//give the path of an image
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write( bImage, "png", baos );
    baos.flush();
    byte[] imageInByteArray = baos.toByteArray();
    baos.close();                                   
    String b64 = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(imageInByteArray);
    %>
    <img style="height:90px" align="center" class="img-responsive" src="data:image/jpg;base64, <%=b64%>" alt="Missing Picture"/>                            
    <% 
}catch(IOException e){
  System.out.println("Error: "+e);
} 


%>
```

This code helped me to insert image in JSP page from my local computer png file.

Comment: you should consider to package the image in your webapp